# firebase storage java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, illegalstateexception

I want to download my all files from the firebase folder on android.

> this is my code

```
try {
        StorageReference reference = storage.getReference().child("Ringtone");
    reference.listAll().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<ListResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ListResult> task) {
            if (task.isComplete()){
            task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {    /////line 82  == 1st line where i am getting error
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
                    for (StorageReference item : listResult.getItems()) {

                        RingtoneModel ringtoneModel = new RingtoneModel();
                        ringtoneModel.setUri(item.getDownloadUrl().getResult());      /////line 88 == 2nd line where i am getting  error here
                        item.getMetadata().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<StorageMetadata>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(StorageMetadata storageMetadata) {
                                ringtoneModel.setSongName(storageMetadata.getName());
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ring name saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Log.e("metadata error",e.getMessage());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });}else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, (CharSequence) task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.e("list all error",e.getMessage());
        }
    }); }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("all errors",e.getMessage());}
}
```

> Logcat error message

```
   /com.example.alarm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.alarm, PID: 433
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete
            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkState(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.zzb(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.getResult(Unknown Source)
            at com.example.alarm.MainActivity$3.onSuccess(MainActivity.java:88)
            at com.example.alarm.MainActivity$3.onSuccess(MainActivity.java:82)
```

my folders and files path in firebase database
`Firebase storage >Rington<my files`

<--what i am tried -->
i tried adding addonsuuccesslistner , addoncompletelitner, task.isComplete(), task.issuccessfull() and may more things

Comment: Could you share line numbers in code? It seems you are assuming the task is complete eagerly when trying to attach success listener, and in the else block attempting to read the exception for an in flight task.

Comment: @trpide yes, line  82 =  task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>()     line 88 =  ringtoneModel.setUri(item.getDownloadUrl().getResult());

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: at line 82 = `task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>()`  and line 88 = `ringtoneModel.setUri(item.getDownloadUrl().getResult())`  both

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While [`addOnSuccessListener`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task#addOnSuccessListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener%3C?%20super%20TResult%3E)) and [`addOnFailureListener`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task#addOnFailureListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener)) are useful for handling the results of an asynchronous task, they aren't very useful when you need to chain things together like you are here.

Looking at your code, you call the following line:

```
StorageReference item;

item.getDownloadUrl().getResult()
```

The exception you get is thrown because you aren't waiting for this task to finish before calling `getResult()`.

```
Task<String> downloadUrlTask = item.getDownloadUrl();

downloadUrlTask
  .addOnSuccessListener(result -> {
    // now do something with result
  })
  .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
    // now do something with the exception
  });
```

While the above code is helpful if that's all you needed, what you are trying to do is wait for it to finish along with `getMetadata()` so you can create an instance of your `RingtoneModel` class.

---

This is where the [`Tasks`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks) utility class comes in.

[`Tasks.whenAll(Collection<Task<?>> tasks)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks#whenAll(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E%3E)) will succeed only when all of the tasks in `tasks` successfully finish.

```
Task<String> downloadUrlTask = item.getDownloadUrl();
Task<StorageMetadata> metadataTask = item.getMetadata();

return Tasks
    .whenAll([ // wait for these tasks to finish successfully
        downloadUrlTask,
        metadataTask
    ])
    .addOnSuccessListener(() -> { // then assemble its RingtoneModel
        RingtoneModel ringtoneModel = new RingtoneModel();
        ringtoneModel.setUri(downloadUrlTask.getResult());
        ringtoneModel.setSongName(metadataTask.getResult().getName());

        // we've now got a RingtoneModel! but what to do with it?
    });
```

Instead of using `addOnSuccessListener()` in the above code, if we use [`onSuccessTask()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task#onSuccessTask(com.google.android.gms.tasks.SuccessContinuation%3CTResult,%20TContinuationResult%3E)) we can return the `RingtoneModel` back so that the `Task<void>` from `Tasks.whenAll()` is now a `Task<RingtoneModel>`. To do this, we need to use [`Tasks.forResult()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks#forResult(TResult)) which will take our `RingtoneModel` and turn it into a `Task<RingtoneModel>`.

```
// function that takes a StorageReference and
// returns a task that resolves to a RingtoneModel
StorageReference item -> {
    Task<String> downloadUrlTask = item.getDownloadUrl();
    Task<StorageMetadata> metadataTask = item.getMetadata();

    return Tasks
        .whenAll([ // wait for these tasks to finish successfully
            downloadUrlTask,
            metadataTask
        ])
        .onSuccessTask(() -> { // then assemble its RingtoneModel
            RingtoneModel ringtoneModel = new RingtoneModel();

            // because these task have finished by now,
            // you can safely use getResult() here
            ringtoneModel.setUri(downloadUrlTask.getResult());
            ringtoneModel.setSongName(metadataTask.getResult().getName());

            return Tasks.forResult(ringtoneModel);
        });
}
```

Now that we have a `RingtoneModel` for one `StorageReference`, we want to turn the `List<StorageReference>` into a `List<RingtoneModel>`. We can do this using

```
List<Task<RingtoneModel>> getRingtoneTasks = listResult.getItems()
    .stream()
    .map(convertToRingtoneModel); // the function above
```

Note here that we have `List<Task<RingtoneModel>>` instead of `Task<List<RingtoneModel>>`. To flip this around, we make use of `Tasks.whenAll()`, `onSuccessTask()`, `stream().map()` and `Tasks.forResult()` again.

```
return Tasks
    .whenAll(getRingtoneTasks)
    .onSuccessTask(() -> {
        return Tasks.forResult(
            getRingtoneTasks
                .stream()
                .map(task -> task.getResult());
        );
    });
```

Now you might look at that block above and think that's a pretty neat method to have as a utility method, and you are right, because you can just use this to do the same thing:

```
return Tasks.whenAllSuccess(getRingtoneTasks);
```

---

Mashing all of this together, gives:

```
public Task<List<RingtoneModel>> getRingtones() {
    StorageReference reference = storage.getReference().child("Ringtone");
    return reference.listAll() // find all objects under /Ringtone
        .onSuccessTask(listResult -> {
            // for each item found, assemble a RingtoneModel
            List<Task<RingtoneModel>> getRingtoneTasks = listResult.getItems()
                .stream()
                .map((item) -> {
                    // A RingtoneModel needs the download URL and the object's metadata
                    Task<String> downloadUrlTask = item.getDownloadUrl();
                    Task<StorageMetadata> metadataTask = item.getMetadata();

                    return Tasks
                        .whenAll([ // wait for these tasks to finish successfully
                            downloadUrlTask,
                            metadataTask
                        ])
                        .onSuccessTask(() -> { // then assemble the RingtoneModel and return it
                            RingtoneModel ringtoneModel = new RingtoneModel();
                            ringtoneModel.setUri(downloadUrlTask.getResult());
                            ringtoneModel.setSongName(metadataTask.getResult().getName());
                            return Tasks.forResult(ringtoneModel);
                        });
                });

            return Tasks.whenAllSuccess(getRingtoneTasks);
        });
}
```

Then when you want to get all the ringtones in your Cloud Storage you just need:

```
getRingtones()
    .addOnSuccessListener(ringtoneModelList -> {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Found " + ringtoneModelList.size() + " ringtones.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // I recommend storing ringtoneModelList in your database of choice
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to get any ringtones.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("getRingtones error", e); // <-- log the full error to help with debugging
    });
```

Comment: thanks bro I wasted a lot of time getting an answer to this question. Truly, thank you from the deep of my heart.

Comment: why you are adding `.whenAll([ // wait for these tasks to finish successfully
        downloadUrlTask,
        metadataTask
    ])` why you are not adding data parallelly. just like this       `metadataTask.addOnSuccessListener(result -> {
  }) .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
  });`

Comment: @SachinBurdak While I could attach the `metadataTask` and `downloadUrlTask` listeners individually, track when they have completed and then return a `Task` that resolves when both have completed, the `Tasks.whenAll` utility method does that for me. I'd be unnecessarily complicating the code and reinventing the wheel. Think of `Tasks.whenAll` as synonymous with JavaScript's own `Promise.all` with the major difference that `Tasks.whenAll` resolves to void, not an array of results. Also, `Tasks.whenAll` will never fail, so a call to its `addOnFailureListener` method is omitted.